# ExpressJS Middleware req, res, next scope

Tags: node.js, express

After studying some Middlewares I have still a question.

Have a look at the following working setup, It just attaches the do it function to the req object so that we can call it in any route just like `req.doit()`

But where does the **req, res, next** come from?,
I never passed them and I am even more curious how it works since the anonymous function (2.) is surrounded by another function (1.) which I even can pass arguments.

MiddleWareTest.js:

```
var test = function(options){ //1.)
    return function(req, res, next) { //2.)
        req.doit = function() {
            console.log('doit')
        }
        next();
    }
}
module.exports = test;
```

app.js:

```
...
var myMiddleware =  require('./MiddlewareTest.js')
app.use(myMiddleware())
...
```

Any suggestions to deepen my knowledge are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember functions are objects in JS, so they can be passed around and returned like any other object.

When you tell express to use your middleware, you are calling the `myMiddleWare` function:

```
app.use(myMiddleWare());
```

this call returns the anon function you labelled as `\\2.`. Express.js will then call it as part of it's middleware stack when processing a request, giving it the `req`, `res` and `next` arguments.

You can always see which arguments are passed to a function by inspecting the `arguments` object. (i.e. `console.log(arguments)`);

Comment: Thank you very much for the additional talk on freenode #node.js !

Answer (score 3):

The parameters (req, res, next) are passed to it when express runs through the middleware chain. Assume that app.use is a (more complicated) version of this:

```
app.use = function(middleware){
  middlewareChain.push(middleware);
}
```

When a request arrives, express runs through the middleware chain, start to finish. The first defined piece of middleware is called, with the current `req`, `res`, and `next`, where `next` is the next piece of middleware in the chain.

At the end of the chain, `next` is just an empty function. Hopefully, by that point, you've done something with the `res` object (like `res.send`).

(2) is surrounded by an anonymous function so that you can pass options in your call to `app.use`. For example, connect's cookieParser accepts a `cookieSecret`. If you're developing middleware that has no options, it's acceptable (but inconsistent) to define it with the arity `(req, res, next)` and skip returning a function. In that case, you could simply write `app.use(myMiddleware)`.

[ExpressJS Docs on Middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#middleware)